# How to make open Jdk 8 Zulu to use dejavu fonts?

Tags: fonts, azul-zulu, azure-zulu, openjdk-8

I have dejavu fonts installed on x/y/z path and I am using open Jdk 8 (Zulu). While using application that runs on Apache I am getting fonts not found error. For your information, webpage application contain image as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add the path to your fonts to `/etc/fonts/fonts.conf`:

```
<fontconfig>
   <dir>x/y/z</dir>
```

Also, you may need to delete `$HOME/.java/fonts/*`